# How to use + and ( or ) with url s query parameter using IntelliJ

Tags: java, rest-assured

I’m having a use case where I need to get response from server where the url looks like the below

```
https://urlname/path?query=test.project+IN+(integer value)+AND+test.folder+IN+(integer value).
```

This url returns json as response body n this is working with postman and browser. 
But I’m getting status code 500 when I hit this from IntelliJ using `io.restassured.response.Response` class methods as below

```java
Response res = given()
                  .auth()
                  .contentType(“json”)
                  .queryParam(query,param)
                  .get(url);
```

Comment: Hi, what the query and param variables are ? You should post the code initializing those variables. Also, what error do you have when you get your 500 HTTP status ? Any body or exception ?

Comment: The query is “query” and parameter is “test.project+IN+(1234)+AND+test.folderId+IN+(5433)”

Comment: And no error with status code 500

Comment: Try `Response res = given().auth().contentType(“json”)        .urlEncodingEnabled(true)
.queryParam(query,param).get(url);`

Comment: @bhusak I already tried that

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This will access the url https://urlname/path?query=test.project+IN+(1234)+AND+test.folderId+IN+(5433)

```
String query = "query";
        String params = "test.project+IN+(1234)+AND+test.folderId+IN+(5433)";
        Response res = given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).auth().basic("", "").queryParam(query, params)
                .urlEncodingEnabled(false).get("https://urlname/path");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution or rather I can found the actual problem that is I was writing the above code on Jira API’s and I was storing the username and password in a string variable which is used inside auth().basic(“”,””).
Since the password are encrypted it was not allowing RestAssured class to post or access the API. 
So I used http clients Base64 password encoding and made the post call.